# Clipper Lib total Area of Paths (plural)

Tags: c#, clipperlib

I've Googled and searched and didn't find anything similar to what I need.

Clipper Lib provides a function to calculate the Area of a Path:

`double Area(Path path)`

I can't find a way to scale this to calculate the area of complex polygon (polygons with holes in them, etc).

Meaning, I need to create something similar to this:

`double Area(Paths paths, PolyFillType FillType = PolyFillType.pftEvenOdd)`

Can please someone enlighten me how to do this?
Thank you in advance

PS: I can't simply make the sum of the areas, because this complex polygon may have holes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Clipper.Area() returns holes as a negative area value, so we can just sum up everything.

```
double CalcArea(List<List<IntPoint>> polygon)
{
    List<List<IntPoint>> paths = Clipper.SimplifyPolygons(polygon);
    double totalArea = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.Count; i++)
        totalArea += Clipper.Area(paths[i]);
    return totalArea;
}
```